# Find the number of ways to write $2017$ in the form $2017 = a_3 \cdot 10^3 + a_2 \cdot 10^2 + a_1 \cdot 10 + a_0.$

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

Find the number of ways to write $2017$ in the form $$2017 = a_3 \cdot 10^3 + a_2 \cdot 10^2 + a_1 \cdot 10 + a_0,$$where the $a_i$'s are integers, and $0 \le a_i \le 99.$ An example of such a representation is $$2017 = 1\cdot 10^3 + 3\cdot 10^2 + 67\cdot 10^1 + 47.$$

---

This problem is a reincarnation of the 2010 AIME I Problem 10.  Instead of 2010, it's 2017.

Comment: I guess $a_3=2$, $a_2=0$, $a_1=1$, $a_0=7$ is also valid :).

Comment: Any thoughts?  Hint:  I'd start with $a_3$ as that is very easy to bound.

Comment: The answer is the same as with $2010$.  Given any solution to $2010$ just add $7$ to $a_0$.  You can always do that because for $2010\ a_0$ had to be a multiple of $10$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Write each of $a_i$ except $a_3$ as $a_i=10b_i+c_i$ where $0\leq b_i,c_i\leq9$ you're left with $$2017=(a_3+b_2)\cdot10^3+(c_2+b_1)\cdot 10^2+(c_1+b_0)\cdot 10+c_0$$